# wp_insert_post custom taxonomy input to multiple posts

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a front end form which will create two individual posts from the one form. My issue is when setting the custom taxonomy for each post, it will only input the first selection and not the full array of selections.

If I remove the [$key] from $services = $taxinput["job_listing_category"][$key];, it will then add all of the taxonomy selections from both inputs to both of the two posts.

I cant work out why I either have just a single taxonomy selection only applied to the correct individual post, or I have all taxonomy selections from both inputs added to both posts.

```
            if($_POST){
                foreach($_POST['class_name_1'] as $key =>$makepost) 
                {              

                    if(strlen($makepost)>3){

                        $post_id = -1;

                        $taxinput = $_POST["tax_input"];                       
                        $services = $taxinput["job_listing_category"][$key];

                        $class_name_1 = $_POST['class_name_1'][$key];

                        $post_id = wp_insert_post(
                                        array(
                                                'comment_status'  =>  'closed',
                                                'ping_status'   =>  'closed',
                                                'post_author'   =>  $author_id,
                                                'post_name'   =>  '',
                                                'post_title'    =>  '',
                                                'post_status'   =>  'pending',
                                                'post_type'   =>  'job_listing',
                                                'post_content'          =>      ''

                                        )
                                );   

                        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $services, 'job_listing_category', true);
                        wp_add_post_meta(  $post_id, 'class_name_1', $class_name_1);

                    }                        
                }
            }
```

Here is my frontend input form:

```
 <form action="" method="post" id="submit-class" class="job-manager-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">


 <div class="class-name-edit">
       <label for="class_name">Class Name:</label>
            <div class="field ">
                   <?php 
                        get_job_manager_template( 'form-fields/text-field.php', 
                            array(
                               'key' => 'class_name_1[]', 
                               'field' => $all_fields['class_name_1']
                               )                        
                        );

                   ?>
            </div>
 </div>



<div class="service-category classes">
      <label for="job_category">Class categories:</label>
         </div>              
            <?php 
            get_job_manager_template( 'form-fields/term-checklist-field.php', 
                array( 
                    'key' => 'job_category[]', 
                    'field' => $all_fields['job_category']
                    )
                );
            ?>
         </div>

</div>


<div class="class-name-edit">
       <label for="class_name">Class Name:</label>
            <div class="field ">
                   <?php 
                        get_job_manager_template( 'form-fields/text-field.php', 
                            array(
                               'key' => 'class_name_1[]', 
                               'field' => $all_fields['class_name_1']
                               )                        
                        );

                   ?>
            </div>
 </div>



<div class="service-category classes">
      <label for="job_category">Class categories:</label>
         </div>              
            <?php 
            get_job_manager_template( 'form-fields/term-checklist-field.php', 
                array( 
                    'key' => 'job_category[]', 
                    'field' => $all_fields['job_category']
                    )
                );
            ?>
         </div>

</div>


  <div class="whitebox submitform">

  <input type="submit" name="submit_job" class="button"   value="Submit for Admin Approval" />

 </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Please, first format our code.

Comment: Formatted - hopefully thats a little easier to read.